# Is there a particular reason why one device is getting half speed all of a sudden and all other devices are unaffected?

Tags: networking

I recently got ATT fiber internet 500. So when it was installed every device was getting at least 500 up and 500 down.

All of a sudden my main used PC is still getting the proper down speeds but roughly a quarter or a third of the upload speed it was getting.

I have a server and it is still getting the same speeds as when the service was connected. Both machines are hard wired through the same switch.

Any suggestions as to what I could try to resolve this?

Comment: Is it only your main PC affected? If other devices are also affected then you may want to enquire with your service provider to check if there's throttling going on with the upload (which is very common).